# Cómo pasar valor de un radio button a un campo hidden

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, radio

Tengo tres radios

```html
<td><label><input type='radio' name='<?php echo $registroAsistencia[1]; ?>' id='presente' value='presente' onclick='valRadio(this)'> Presente</label></td> <input type ='hidden' name ='presente2' id="presente2"> lo que necesito es pasar el value hacia mi hidden en el POST lo que recibo es esto Array ( [bEnviar] =&gt; //este es el boton [okokok] =&gt; presente//todo lo demas es los datos de la bd. [diana] =&gt; presente [luis] =&gt; ausente [juan] =&gt; excusa )
```

Necesito pasar el valor de un `radio button` a un `input type="hidden"`, para poder procesarlo en **PHP**.

```html
<td><label><input type='radio' name='<?php echo $registroAsistencia[1]; ?>' id='presente' value='presente'> Presente</label></td>
<input type="hidden" name ="presente2" id="presente2">
```

no se si es la mejor manera, solo que me recomendaron entrar su valor al hidden ya que no lo puedo recibir por post debido a que ocupo el name con una variable proveniente de php

Con esta función funcionaria perfecto solo que solo funciona para el campo text no para el radio

```html
<script> $(document).ready(function () { $("#texto1").keyup(function () { var value = $(this).val(); $("#texto2").val(value); }); }); </script>
```

y no logre hacerlo con ella

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
 //selecciono mi radio
 var miRadio = document.getElementById('miRadio');
 //ejecuto la funcion "miFuncion" en el evento onclick
 miRadio.onclick = miFuncion;
 function miFuncion(){
 //agrego el valor del radio a mi input
 document.getElementById('inputOculto').value=miRadio.value;
 }//end function miFuncion
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="miRadio" id="miRadio" value="presente">Presente
<input type="hidden" id="inputOculto" name="inputOculto">
```

Si te fijas lo que haces primero es seleccionar tu radio mediante un **ID** luego escucho el evento **onclick** del radio y ejecuto una funcion "miFuncion" donde defino el valor del radio hacia el input oculto.

Espero te sirva y suerte.

Comment: Saludos Diego y gracias por contestar.  te explico tengo tres radios <td><label><input type='radio' name='<?php echo $registroAsistencia[1]; ?>' id='presente' value='presente' onclick='valRadio(this)'> Presente</label></td>     <input  type ='hidden'  name ='presente2' id="presente2">                       lo que necesito es pasar el value hacia mi hidden     en el POST lo que recibo es esto Array
(
[bEnviar] =&gt; //este es el boton
[okokok] =&gt; presente//todo lo demas es los datos de la bd.
[diana] =&gt; presente
[luis] =&gt; ausente
[juan] =&gt; excusa
)

Comment: no se si es la mejor manera, solo que me recomendaron entrar su valor al hidden ya que no lo puedo recibir por post debido a que ocupo el name con una variable proveniente de php

Comment: con esta funcion funcionaria perfecto solo que solo funciona para el campo text no para el radio <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#texto1").keyup(function () {
              var value = $(this).val();
              $("#texto2").val(value);
          });
      });
</script> y no logre hacerlo con ella

Comment: @alvarowhite eso que le estás explicando a Diego debes agregarlo a tu pregunta, dar la mayor información posible, fue por eso que la edite para mejorar el formato pero no la respondí....edítala por favor y agrega mas información

Comment: ok. ya la actualice.